# Question About The Re-expression of The Following Statement: "I will go to work either tomorrow or today."

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have the following statement:

"I will go to work either tomorrow or today."

By assigning the statement "I will go to work today." as $P$ and "I will go to work tomorrow." as $Q$, I got the expression,

\begin{equation*}
P \vee Q
\end{equation*}

However, I wonder that could the statement be expressed as follow:

\begin{equation*}
(A \vee B) \implies W
\end{equation*}

where $A$ denotes "It is tomorrow.", $B$ denotes "It is today.", and $W$ denotes "I will go to work." which the expression translates as the English language statement: "If it is today or tomorrow, then I will go to work."

---

Reference:
Velleman, D. J. (2019). How to Prove It: A Structured Approach. Cambridge University Press, 3. edition, p.8.

Comment: It's a little open to interpretation, it depends whether the sentence "I will go to work either tomorrow or today" implies that this is the only day (perhaps of the week ?) that you'll go to work.

Comment: IMO the natural language statement reads: "Either I will go to work  tomorrow or I will go to work today".

Comment: You don't even know $B\implies W$, let alone $(A\lor B)\implies W$, What you have is $(A\to W)\lor(B\to W)$ (note $\to$ is weaker than $\implies$, since $X\to Y$ means $Y\lor\neg X$).

Comment: @J.G. Can you elaborate the differences between $\implies$ and $\to$? I am on the first chapter of the book I refered to in the post and I have no idea why the two are different.

Comment: @Approxiz $X\implies Y$ is typically shorthand for $X\to Y$ being provable, either as a tautology or from some assumptions we take as given, such as a theory. If all you meant to imply was $(A\lor B)\to W$, that still differs from $(A\to W)\lor(B\to W)$ if $(A\not\equiv B)\land\neg W$.

Comment: @J.G. Also, is it the case that $(A \to W) \vee (B \to W)$ refer to the statement where the person who announces the statement work for only one day? What about some other statement where the person who announces the statement can work for both days?

Comment: If they can work at least one but possibly both days, that's $\lor$; if they can work exactly one day, [that's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) $\oplus$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose I know that I will go to work tomorrow but not today.

Then it is accurate for me to announce that I will go to work either tomorrow or today.

But this true (in a literal sense) announcement is not equivalent to the false declaration "If it is today or tomorrow, then I will go to work (on said day)."

Propositional logic generally isn't a good fit for imperatives and tenses.

Comment: On the said day(today), is it the case that the truth value for the false implication, "If it is today or tomorrow, then I will go to work.", cannot be determined? because the truth value for the antecedent is true but the truth value for the consequent is unknown.

Comment: @Approxiz My answer supplies an interpretation such that the second statement's consequent has truth value $0.$ Notice that "I will go to work" by itself is ambiguous (you will go to work....when? ever?), and, guessing that you actually intend your consequent to depend on the antecedent, I'd added a "on said day"; in other words, your second statement translates to $\forall x\;[A(x)∨B(x){\implies}W(x)],$ so is in predicate rather than propositional logic.